# c# - An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll Additional information: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, graphics

I'm trying to make a loading animation using Graphics in winform panel. The angle of the loader changes in a background worker and then takes a Sleep and then again again changes.

Here's the LoadingAnimation class code :

```
class LoadingAnimation : Panel
{
    int _angle = 0;
    float _penSize = 12f;

    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("Gets or sets the angle.")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public int Angle
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _angle; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _angle = value;

            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("Gets or sets the pen size.")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public float PenSize
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _penSize;
        }
        set 
        { 
            _penSize = value;

            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 162, 255), _penSize))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, (_penSize / 2) + 1, (_penSize / 2) + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Width - (_penSize + 2), this.ClientRectangle.Height - (_penSize + 2));

            p.Color = Color.White;

            e.Graphics.DrawArc(p, (_penSize / 2) + 1, (_penSize / 2) + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Width - (_penSize + 2), this.ClientRectangle.Height - (_penSize + 2), _angle, 90);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the background worker dowork event which updates the angle.

```
void Animator_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (angle > 359)
                {
                    angle = 0;
                }

                if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 90)
                {
                    time = 8;
                }

                if (angle > 90 && angle <= 180)
                {
                    time = 15;
                }


                if (angle > 180 && angle <= 270)
                {
                    time = 20;
                }

                if (angle > 170 && angle <= 359)
                {
                    time = 2;
                }

                picStatus.Angle = angle;

                angle++;

                Thread.Sleep(time);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

It is working fine till the form size does not changes. When I minimize the form and then return the form back to the original state its throws an error

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll*

*Additional information: Parameter is not valid.*

Its does not shows or jumps to any line where the exception has occured, just points to the main winform constructor call.

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

***UPDATE:***

I tried doing same by using an image and rotate it. For image rotation I referred and used code from this article.
[C# Image/PictureBox Rotations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations)

And used this code for picture rotation

```
void ImageRotator_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (angle > 359)
                {
                    angle = 0;
                }

                if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 90)
                {
                    time = 8;
                }

                if (angle > 90 && angle <= 180)
                {
                    time = 15;
                }


                if (angle > 180 && angle <= 270)
                {
                    time = 20;
                }

                if (angle > 170 && angle <= 359)
                {
                    time = 2;
                }

                //Store our old image so we can delete it
                Image oldImage = picStatus.BackgroundImage;
                //Pass in our original image and return a new image rotated 35 degrees right
                picStatus.BackgroundImage = Utilities.RotateImage(Resources.Loader, angle);

                if (oldImage != null)
                {
                    oldImage.Dispose();
                }

                angle++;

                Thread.Sleep(time);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

But the problem remains the same. Same error as given in screenshot.

Comment: Put a try-catch block in OnPaint, your exception is there... "DrawEllipse or DrawArc".

Comment: @x... No Success. Tried putting in try catch block but having same problem again.

Comment: Do you use 3rd party dll for drawing ?

Comment: @x... No third party library

Comment: Then...bug report to Microsoft...:=)

Comment: @x... Hmm. okay. Any other work around or library for Image and Graphics???

Comment: Don't know about that. I always use from Microsoft and never had a bug during drawing.

Comment: @x... okay. Let's see if anyone else has solution or workaround.. Waiting for solution.